# CSS DRY concept applied

Tags: css

I have the following CSS:

```
    &.fixed-map {
      width: 100%!important;
      position: fixed!important;
      left: 0;
    }
    &.under-750 {
      width: 100%!important;
      position: static;
    }
    &.over-1025 {
      position: static;
    }
```

Does this have a performance boost from a CSS perspective?

```
&.fixed-map,
&.under-750 {
  width: 100%!important;
}
&.under-750,
&.over-1025 {
  position: static;
}
&.fixed-map {
    position: fixed!important;
    left: 0;
}
```

or is it only a better way of writing the CSS?

Comment: sass-lang.com/guide - part about Variables might come handy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From agile point of view I would definitely use the first way.
Such optimisations (if it really is an optimisation) are to be handled by machines. Not coders.

Imagine, you wanted to modify width of `.under-750`.

**Use the first way.**

sidenote: Only use `important!` only as the very last possibility.

Answer (score 2):

The performance boost you're getting from DRYing your code is essentially negligible. The bonuses you get from applying a DRY principle to CSS have to do with how *you* (and other developers) will understand it.

Of course, you may see a slight performance gain if you were to extrapolate your example to a massive codebase, but the benefits of DRY are more for comprehension than making your CSS more performant.

Concepts like DRY are important to keep in mind while creating CSS, but they are not rules to die by. Repetition in your CSS is not a cardinal sin if it helps you to understand what is happening.

I hope that you're serving your CSS files with *gzip compression*, and I would recommend that you do if you aren't; from a performance point of view, repetition in CSS served over gzip is handled very well. This is why you'll find that generally, it is no longer recommended to silo your *media queries* into their own blocks, which contain the styles for each particular *media expression*. It's much easier to understand how styles are modified in media queries if they are right next to the styles they modify in your CSS.

I'd also recommend against writing class-names which are directly related to the visual styles they apply, *i.e.* rethink how you're naming `.under-750` and `.over-1025`, as I'm sure 750 and 1025 relate to some pixel values you're setting elsewhere.

---

**tl;dr**: There is no cut and dry (pun intended) correct answer. DRY is a fantastic concept to keep at the front of your mind when writing CSS, but ultimately you should strive to write understandable and maintainable CSS.